# Javascript SDK in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, authentication, sdk

I am building this Website in ASP.NET that needs a Log in with Facebook button (and later with Google) integrated with it to create an account.

I have looked at some great sources like
http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/04/aspnet-integrate-facebook-login.html
and
http://facebooksdk.net/docs/web/getting-started/

[1] However, those examples never deal with Masterpages and content placeholders. So when I am trying to integrate them in the content pages, I get errors because for instance the login button called

```
"fb:login-button scope="email" data-size="large" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="true" onlogin="window.location='/Main.aspx'">
```

Log in with Facebook `< fb:login-button>"`

is not accepted without the html tag

```
html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

which I cannot place on a content page anyways.

[2] Also, I want the user to create an account using their Facebook login. The account is really meant to be used as an instance so that a parent can sign up multiple children for a Summer Program, so all I need the application to do is associate the Facebook login with a new/existing account on my application. Any tips on how to handle this would also be greatly appreciated.

[3] Lastly, after a user logs into facebook, I would like to see them redirected to another page. However, in the code-behind file for the page, I cannot use the Facebook attributes that were written in Javascript and since the Facebook button was not an element of the toolbox, I cannot create an event handler for that. Instead, I had to write

```
onlogin="window.location='/Main.aspx'
```

within the tags of the Facebook button. This is not ideal because that means everytime I click that Facebook button, it will redirect me to Main.aspx. Meaning that if I were logged into Facebook already, and ran the Web site, I would click on "Log out" and still access the Main.aspx page...

Hope there's someone out there that has been in the same situation... or can help me!
I have been researching this for 12 hours straight now and cannot get anywhere :(

Comment: Even more lastly that that - please try to ask one question per post. Check http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275908/more-than-one-question-per-post?cb=1 for recommendations.

Comment: Side note: please don't add "thank you notes", "searched alot" and other text not related to problem in the post. When writing title don't add tags, but instead have main idea of the question be present in the title.